# Upgrade from Tortoise Hg 3.0 to 3.1 -- Python subprocess calls

Tags: python, mercurial, subprocess, tortoisehg

I've recently updated from TortoiseHg 3.0.1 to 3.1.1.

This is breaking a custom Python script that overwrites a commit in the GUI due to a subprocess call.
The subprocess simply prompts a user for an input.

Basically, along the lines of

```
def commit_user(orig,ui,repo,*pats,**opts):
    subprocess.call(["C:\test.exe"])
    orig(ui,repo,*pats,**opts)

def uisetup(ui):
    extensions.wrapcommand(commands.table, 'commit', commit_user)
```

where test.exe contains a simple input prompt

However, while in 3.0.1 the subprocess.call() was opened in a new command window (by default), 3.1.1 appears to not do this, where there is a timeout on the input call. How can I get the same behaviour in 3.1.1 as 3.0.1?

I've tried messing around with shell, stdin, stdout parameters for subprocess.call but I appear to only break things more.

It works in command line, where the input and output streams are simply tied to the command shell but not in TortoiseHg, where I've read there is no actual stdin, and stdout and stderr are simply placed into the ui output logs.

**Edit:** I've since tried no input commands such as:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["cmd"],stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
```

which also seems to hang.
Is there an alternative to calling command line style commands in Python that could work from TortoiseHg?

**Edit2:**

```
os.system("cmd")
```

also breaks. 
All methods have the same error:

```
cmdserver: timed out while reading: 'Microsoft Windows [V'...
```

so it does appear something always partially runs in the background somewhere, where a new process can be seen to be hanging in task manager.

**Edit3:** So finally after some research... 3.1 has a major change to stdin and stdout, where everything is fed to a "server".

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CommandServer

Comment: If your Edit3 - "Command Server" is the answer to your original question, please post it as an actual answer and give it the check mark so future folks know what you found!

Comment: Haven't had the opportunity to mess around with command server stuff so unsure if this will solve my problem and that I'd get access to a simple input/output dialogue. Also, ideally I'd have nothing to do with the server (so I could avoid having to update as much as possible between new TortoiseHg versions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out there is an extremely simple fix to all of this, with a creation flag in the subprocess parameters.

```
from subprocess import CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

subprocess.call(['test.exe'], creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

alternatively there is also the option to mess around with the full set of behind the scenes flags in subprocess.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STARTUPINFO